# Opening Activity Crashes App

Tags: class, android-activity, onclicklistener

Hey guys I'm new to coding and iv'e recently been working on an app. I have set OnClickListener's to my buttons each leading to another class that I believe I stated in the Manifest. When I launch my app one of the buttons works but the other crashes the app and tells me that the class is not found please help. Here is some code:

```
    public class CharPage extends ActionBarActivity {
private static Button button_next;
private static Button button_kk;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_char_page);
    OnClickButtonListener();
}
public void OnClickButtonListener() {
{
    button_kk= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonkk);
    button_kk.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     Intent intent = new        Intent("com.example.jmac.mortalkombat.Kotal_Khan");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
}
button_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

button_next.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.jmac.mortalkombat.CharPage2");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
);
```

}

Then there is my Manifest:

```
     <activity
        android:name=".CharPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CharPage2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_char_page2" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.jmac.mortalkombat.CharPage2" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CharPage3"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_char_page3" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.jmac.mortalkombat.CharPage3" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Kotal_Khan"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kotal__khan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.jmac.mortalkombat.Kotal_Khan" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

The StackTrace:
 26010-26010/com.example.jmac.mortalkombat E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.jmac.mortalkombat, PID: 26010
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.jmac.mortalkombat.Kotal_Khan }
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1801)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1499)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3942)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3889)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:820)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4213)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4181)
            at com.example.jmac.mortalkombat.CharPage$1.onClick(CharPage.java:37)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20926)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Comment: add your stack trace please.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying quickly where would I find the stack trace?

Comment: in the logcat of Eclipse or android Studio.

Comment: Sure thing ill grab that now.

Comment: Thats the error im assuming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you have an Activity in your project that has this name "Kotal_Khan" and is under the package "com.example.jmac.mortalkombat" since this is what you declared in your manifest.

Second Replace.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.jmac.mortalkombat.Kotal_Khan");
```

for

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YOURCLASSNAME.class);
```

i assume will be Kotal_Khan.class.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks alot brah ill try this out!

Comment: Yes I tried it and it seemed to not work at first which puzzled me so i just recreated the activity because i figured it was the IDE's fault and it started to work!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_char_page);
    button_kk= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonkk);
    button_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    OnClickButtonListener();
}
public void OnClickButtonListener() {
{

    button_kk.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     Intent intent = new        Intent("com.example.jmac.mortalkombat.Kotal_Khan");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );


button_next.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.jmac.mortalkombat.CharPage2");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
);
}
```